# Creating a single <input> type with multiple fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

Edited for clarity:

Although this question was answered by @grateful, I'll try to expand it in case it should prove useful to others...

My project contains a page, rsetup.php, that contains some php that accesses a MySQL database to populate the HTML portion of the page. The HTML creates a form with "standard"  fields like radiobuttons, checkboxes and text fields.

One of the sections of the form has multiple instances of a database field that are used to create an optional "filter chain". The type of input field I'm looking to implements looks like:

[label][op][value]

Where label is the name of a filter, op is either ==, != or NULL and value is an arbitrary operand (usually a string). Ideally the input type will return all three subfields when queried.

The answer provided by @grateful below pointed me in the right direction. A few tweaks and it will do exactly what I need. If anyone else in the community needs a similar solution, this is a great starting point.

I'm sorry there are no code examples to illustrate this question but the project is internal to the company I work for and I'm pretty sure any public exposure would be frowned upon...

Thank you in advance for any help,
405nm

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: probably 2 selects and 1 text input, but whats the actual question?

Comment: you can use one input with a `pattern` attrib to validate, or try to composite 3 inputs into one virtual one, which would need a custom element to function correctly in forms as one input....

Comment: Actually @grateful pretty much answered the question in the last post. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the tricky thing is getting the css right - making the 3 parts look like part of the same input field. To do this, it's good to give them the same class name and set their appearance attribute to 'none', ie:

```
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance:    none;
  appearance:         none;
```

However, having done this, you need to restyle the elemnts, hence quite a lot of css.
I created an example for you on Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/circuittree/pen/dXNaEo)

Comment: Thanks @grateful, your answer and example are almost exactly what I was attempting to do. Thanks much!

Comment: You are welcome @405nm. Can you accept the answer please?